# How to call ASP.NET DropdownList SelectedIndexChanged event handler with custom arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms, dropdown

I need DropDownList with custom arguments to be called. As I want to send some custom event ( custom data ) to event handler, Therefore want to hookup or intercept `DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged` event so that I can extract the information from it.

at some point in the code :

```
dropdownList.SelectedIndexchanged += new EventHandler(AzureService_CommonResourceGroupSelectedIndexChanged);

  protected void AzureService_CommonResourceGroupSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, MyEvnetArgs e)
    {
        // Want to populated other dynamic ASP.NET Dropdown control on the same dialog. So that's why need to get the corresponding control name info here.
    }
```

Any idea how this can be achieved? But don't know how to pass MyEventArgs to handler. Is it possible to hook or intercept the call somehow?
Would be obliged to have the answer.

**Edit**

```
AzureService_CommonResourceGroupSelectedIndexChanged handler should receive as Eventargs extra data which I can use to query what kind of dropdownlist is intended to be cascade in the course of the click of the first one. I am working on cascading drop-down boxes.
```

Dropdown 1 - clicked should cascade another drop-down box (have to inform its handler to whom other drop-down lists it has to populate).

[image: ![enter image description here]

Here Dropdown 1 data will be populated from the source. User will select something from dropdown 1 list and as result other dependent drop downs will be populated. **The Handler further will use the Html instance of drop down2 and drop down3 for populating its data**.

So, I need to inform dropdwon1 somehow which other drop downs it has to poulate.

Thanks

Comment: Explain your problem.  What are you trying to achieve.  Extending dropdown is not that simple if you might not be comfortable with it, so maybe there is easier solution.  If you explain what type of data you want etc then someone might be able to guide you.

Comment: Well, what extra data or values do you need/want to pass? I mean, hidden controls on the page, or even just grabbing values from controls on the page is possible. So it not clear what extra values you could/would send on that event compared to the code behind in that event just grabbing/taking such values. Now it possible you  have a grid or some such - but that would be a significant detail you left out

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own delegate and chain the handlers.

```
dropdownList.SelectedIndexchanged += new EventHandler(MyEventHandler);

protected void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var e2 = new MyEventArgs { SomeVariable = "Whatever" };
    AzureService_CommonResourceGroupSelectedIndexChanged(sender, e2);
}
```